# Colors on the screen is washed

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, colors, color-management

I tried xgamma, xrandr everything, none works.

This is how my screen looks now, the colors are dull.

[image]

Now for vlc I can change color settings for the video, to get an output like this. Please note that since your monitor is in the right configuration, the first picture might look normal and the second one bit more colored to you.

[image]

I want my screen to have the same color profile all the time, not just on vlc player. How do I do it?

I'm on an old HP laptop with intel 4400 graphics, using i915 driver for linux. When I was on windows I had intel control panel to set the contrast, but it's seems impossible in linux. Xgamma only do gamma correction, not contrast. I found a gui application called kolorcontrol, but it won't let me increase contrast more than 100%, which is already my screen is at.

I have moderate programming skills, is it possible to write a code to increase the contrast of the frame? Where do I start?